# Operator norm of $\|\mathrm{e}^{-tA}\|$, $A$ normal, $t \geq 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

$\newcommand{\e}{\mathrm{e}}\renewcommand{\Re}{\operatorname{Re}}$Suppose $A$ a bounded, normal linear operator on a Hilbert space $H$ such that $\Re\lambda \geq 0$ for all $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$. I'm trying to show $\|\e^{-tA}\|_{\mathrm{op}}\leq 1$ for $t\geq 0$ but am stuck. The usual trick doesn't work since;
$$
\|\e^{-tA}\|
= \Big\|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-tA)^n/n!\Big\|
\leq \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(|t|\|A\|)^n}{n!}
= \e^{\|tA\|}
\rightarrow \infty
$$

I suspect I want to land on somthing like;

$\e^{-t\|A\|}$ using $\|A\|^n=\|A^n\|$, but I can't seem to make it work.

Comment: You have to use the spectral calculus for the normal operator $A$. Then
$$
\mathrm{e}^{-tA} = \int_{\sigma(A)} \mathrm{e}^{-t\lambda} \,\mathrm{d}E(\lambda).
$$
Applying the norm and triangular inequality will yield the result.

Comment: This looks to be well above my level at the moment (I have no idea what you mean by $dE(\lambda)$) but  have a result in my notes; $$||f(A)||=sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}||f(\lambda)|$$ So I think I can write; $$||e^{-tA}||=\sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}|e^{-t\lambda}|=\sup_{\lambda \in \sigma(A)}|e^{-ta}e^{-(tb)i}|=\sup_{a \geq 0}|e^{-ta}|\leq 1 $$

Comment: @Muselive That definitely seems like the way to go. If you're curious, the comment and answer are referring to the spectral theorem (for bounded normal operators).

Comment: @Muselive $E$ denotes the spectral measure of $A$. The result from your notes seem like a corollary of the spectral theorem. However, I think continuous function you can also arrive there with Gelfand theory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false. In the one-dimensional case the inequality becomes $|e^{-ta}| \leq 1$ for any real number $a$ and any $t \geq 0$ which is false.

For the edited version use Functional Calculus to show that the spectral radius of $e^{-tA}$ is at most $1$.

Comment: Im missing condition, sorry; added that the real part of $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ is always non-negative.