# If $Re \lambda \geq 0$ for all $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$ show $Re\langle x,Ax\rangle\geq 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $H$ be a Hilbert space and A a normal operator with the property $Re\lambda\geq 0$ for all $\lambda \in \sigma(A)$. We want to show that $Re\left<x,Ax\right> \geq 0$ for every $x \in h$.

I have a hint which says to first show $||e^{-tA}||\leq 1$ when $t \geq 0$ which I think I have [Post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4126631/operator-norm-of-mathrme-ta-a-normal-t-geq-0)

The next hint says to differentiate the map $x \mapsto ||e^{-tA}x||^2$

So I suppose $F_x(t)=||e^{-tA}x||^2$ and calculate;

$$\frac{d}{dt}F_x(t)=\frac{d}{dt}||e^{-At}x||^2=\frac{d}{dt}\left<e^{-tA}x,e^{-tA}x\right>$$
$$=?=\left<-Ae^{-tA}x,e^{-tA}x\right>+\left<e^{-tA}x,-Ae^{-tA}x\right>$$

Which is where I'm stuck. I have that this expression is equal to;

$$-2Re\left<e^{-tA}x,Ae^{-tA}x\right>$$
and/or $$-\left<e^{-tA}x,(A^*+A)e^{-tA}x\right>$$

But I can't see how either of these give me any insight about $\left<x,Ax\right>$.

Comment: Your calculation means that this derivative at $0$ is 
$\frac{d}{dt}F_x(t)\bigg|_{t=0}=-2Re\left<x,Ax\right>$.
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple answer using the so called [continuous functional calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_functional_calculus), which is applicable since $A$ is normal.

Define the operator $B=A+A^*$. It suffices to show that $\langle Bx,x\rangle\geq0$. Indeed, if we do that then $\langle Ax,x\rangle+\langle A^*x,x\rangle\geq0$, i.e. $\langle Ax,x\rangle+\overline{\langle Ax,x\rangle}\geq0$, i.e. $2\text{Re}\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq0$.

Note that, if $f(z)=z+\bar{z}$, then $B=f(A)$, so $\sigma(B)=f(\sigma(A))=\{z+\bar{z}:z\in\sigma(A)\}=\{2\text{Re}(z):z\in\sigma(A)\}\subset[0,\infty)$, hence $B\geq0$. But positive operators have positive square roots, so $B=C^2$ for some self-adjoint operator $C$ (i.e. use functional calculus again and set $C=g(B)$, where $g(t)=t^{1/2}$), thus $\langle Bx,x\rangle=\langle C^2x,x\rangle=\langle Cx,Cx\rangle=\|Cx\|^2\geq0$.

Answer (score 1):

I guess OP would prefer a different answer; based on folouer of kaklas's comment, indeed the derivative at $0$ is equal to $-2\text{Re}\langle Ax,x\rangle$. But note that $F_x(t)$ is decreasing at 0: if $t>0$, then
$$F_x(t)=\|e^{-tA}x\|^2\leq\|e^{-tA}\|^2\|x\|^2\leq\|x\|^2=F_x(0).$$

Thus $\frac{d}{dt}F_x(t)\vert_{t=0}\leq0$, which is obviously equivalent to what you wanted to prove.

Regarding the question mark in your computations, see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3751058/why-is-ft-eta-differentiable-in-a-unital-banach-algebra/3751085#3751085) (and don't worry about Banach algebras, just think of the bounded operators instead).